# Linking phpcpp fails when building PHP extension

Tags: php, php-extension, php-cpp

**Environment:**
I am trying to develop a PHP-CPP extension and have downloaded the the empty extension file from https://www.php-cpp.com/documentation/your-first-extension to start. I have also modified the makefile's `INI_DIR` variable to point to the correct path.

**Problem:**
When I try to `make` the empty extension it fails to create the shared library file and says `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lphpcpp`.
I'm pretty sure I have php-cpp downloaded correctly, so I have no idea what's wrong. (I have also searched the internet and have found no solutions)

**PHP version**: `7.4`

**System**: `Elementary-OS (Ubuntu)`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that when I first ran `make` to compile php-cpp it didn't make the `libphpcpp.so` file. So, I reinstalled it from Github and built it again and it worked. I don't know why I didn't try that the first time.